# Winforms listview programatically cancel item edit

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a listview control in a winforms app (yes, there is still development done in winforms). The listview is set up so the user can click on the first column and start editing.

I also have a button that does other things, and then updates the listview consequence of other actions.

How can I tell the list view to cancel the editor? I need to do this so a bug does not creep up were I end up with a repeated item

Answer (score 0):

As soon as I post it I though of the solution, so if anybody needs it:

```
listViewControl.Focus( );
SendKeys.Send( "{ESC}" );
```